# Reusing SWIG mappings in custom typemap

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm currently working on a Python wrapper for a C++ library for which I want to use SWIG. In my C++ library I have a method with the following signature:

```
std::vector<SomeClass> getMembers();
```

Now I know that SWIG has built-in std::vector support but I want to explicitly convert std::vectors to Python Lists (I just think it is cleaner). For that I have the following typemap:

```
template<typename T>
PyObject* toList(vector<T> vec){
    size_t size = vec.size();
    PyObject *o = PyList_New(size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        PyList_SetItem(o, i, toPythonInstance<T>(vec[i]));
    }
    return o;
}

%define OUTPUT_VEC_TO_LIST(type)
%typemap (out) std::vector<type> {
    $result = toList<type>($1);
}
%enddef
```

Now the template method:

```
template<T>
PyObject* toPythonInstance(T& val){}
```

Can be specialized to add support for the necessary datatypes. The problem I'm facing now is the following:

**SomeClass** is wrapped automatically by SWIG. So what I like to do is to reuse this wrapper in my vector type map, i.e. have the following:

```
template<>
PyObject* toPythonInstance<SomeClass>(SomeClass& val){
    //call some SWIG macro to automatically wrap the given instance to
    //a Python object
}
```

Inspecting the code generated by SWIG, I already found the following functions

```
SWIG_NewPointerObj(...);
SWIG_ConvertPtr(...);
```

which seem to be responsible for doing exactly what I want. However, I do not want to interfere with any internals of SWIG. So if somebody knows how to achieve what I want with the "public" SWIG interface, I would be very glad!

Comment: You might want to look at https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. It is similar to Swig, and as long as you can convert SomeClass to Python, it will automatically convert std::vector<SomeClass> to Python's lists.

Comment: The functions you're looking at aren't private internals - see http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Modules.html#Modules_external_run_time

Comment: @Flexo: This is the answer to my question so if you want to write it up as one I'm glad to accept it! :)

Comment: @sangrey: The PyBind11 suggestion is just perfect! I tried it out and decided to start using it instead of SWIG since it has everything I need but makes it much easier to use than SWIG - and since I only need a Python Interface, the ease of use is the deciding factor.

Answer (score 1):

SWIG actually makes a whole bunch of runtime information part of an external interface, see http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Modules.html#Modules_external_run_time for details. This includes the functions you're likely to want for your efforts.

I disagree with your assessment that mapping `std::vector` to list is cleaner in Python - you always end up copying and visiting every member of that vector to do this. In effect you make a copy of the original container and end up with two containers, so changes to the Python list won't be reflected back on the underlying C++ container. The Python supplied `std::vector` wrapping should implement the protocols you care about to enable pythonic syntax by default, and can support the [ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) correctly too.. (And if they don't I'm up for writing patches!)